# Presenting an Interstitial Ad in a Game Over Scene linking to GameViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, scene, interstitial

I've integrated a banner view into a scene within my application however I'm failing to integrate a Interstitial ad within another scene.
Here is my code:
import SpriteKit
import GameKit
import GoogleMobileAds

```
 class GameOverMenu: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,    UIAlertViewDelegate {

var viewController: GameViewController!
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

var myTimer = Timer()


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

 createAndLoadInterstitial()

startMyTimer()




}


func createAndLoadInterstitial() {
interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "...")
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "..." ]
interstitial.load(request)
}


func startMyTimer() {
myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(GameOverMenu.myFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func myFunction(){

if interstitial.isReady {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: viewController)
} else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
}

 }
```

It is failing when it tries to load with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The problem lies below as if the code is displayed like this and I load the GameOver scene when the application launches it works fine. How can I fix this?

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {




    // Load the SKScene from 'MainMenu.sks'
    if let scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenu") {

        scene.viewController = self

        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)


    }

    if let scene3 = GameOverMenu(fileNamed: "GameOver") {

        scene3.viewController = self

        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene3.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        view.presentScene(scene3)





    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you transition between 2 scenes you loose the reference to GameViewController e.g

```
 scene3.viewController = self
```

thats why it only works when you launch the application.

You are also using ! on those properties

```
 var viewController: GameViewController!
 var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
```

so if they are nil you will crash. So you should alway use ? when you are not 100% sure that something is there.

```
 var viewController: GameViewController?
 var interstitial: GADInterstitial?
```

and than in your code such as "myFunction" you will use the "?" and "if let" to not crash when the properties are nil.

```
  if let ad = interstitial, let vc = viewController, ad.isReady {
       ad.present(fromRootViewController: vc)
   } else {
       print("Ad wasn't ready")
   }
```

The general fix for your problem is that you should really move all your AdMob code directly into GameViewController. Than you can use something like NotificationCenter or delegation to forward a message from your scenes to your ViewController to show the ad. Its not really the best practice to reference your ViewController in your SKScenes.

So move all the ad code to your ViewController and than in GameViewController outside the class implementation create this extension for the notification key

```
 extension Notification.Name {
       static let showAd = Notification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationShowAd")
 } 

  class GameViewController: UIViewController {...
```

Than in GameViewController in ViewDidLoad you can add the observer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

         createAndLoadInterstitial()

         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunction), name: .showAd, object: nil)

         ....
 }
```

Now whenever you need to show an ad from any of your SKScenes you can call this

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .showAd, object: nil)
```

To make your life even easier have a look at my helper on GitHub

https://github.com/crashoverride777/SwiftyAds

hope this helps